# How to rebuild all library after upgrading Go 1.4

Tags: go, upgrade

I was using Go 1.3.3. After installing 1.4, there are many errors similar to this:

```
db/base.go:4: import /home/asd/Dropbox/go/pkg/linux_amd64/projc1/libs/Bool.a: 
 object is [linux amd64 go1.3.3 X:precisestack] 
  expected [linux amd64 go1.4 X:precisestack]
```

How do I resolve this? I've tried `go build` on `$GOPATH/src/projc1/libs/Bool/` but it has no effect.

Comment: This is related to: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6534

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`go build -a`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) to force rebuilding of existing packages.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `go install -a ...` instead? https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3036

Comment: First tried:go build -a  
did not help
then I tried:
$go install -a   
certainly did the trick.

Comment: If using constabulary gb it´s `gb build -f`

Answer (score 12):

Ah I see, removing `/home/asd/Dropbox/go/pkg/linux_amd64/projc1/` would solve this problem.

Comment: Removing already compiled packages will solve the error message, but the packages are not recompiled automatically so every 'go build' recompiles every package. 'go install' should compile and save the package for later reuse.